# Problems using pubsub and passing definitions in python

Tags: python, wxpython, publish-subscribe, pyodbc

I'm having problem when I subscribe message from pubsub in the childframe class. I can't figure out how write correct code which will show selects from the mainframe. I also can't pass definition row in the childframe class. I don't know how I specified my question I know it's hard to understand, but in this code I think you will find exactly what i was asking for. I'm new in python so plizz don't criticize

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=10.75.79.215;DATABASE=HUB_DATA;UID=sa;PWD=password")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()




class Mainframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.quote1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label = "id")
        self.test=wx.StaticText(self.panel, label = "")
        self.editquote1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size = (140, -1))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label = "search")


    #
        self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

    #
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(6, 6)
        self.sizer.Add(self.quote1, (0, 0))
        self.sizer.Add(self.editquote1, (0, 1))


        self.sizer.Add(self.button, (3, 1))
        self.sizer.Add(self.test, (4, 1))


    #
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 6)

    #
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.windowSizer)

    #
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onbutton and self.afterOnbutton)




    def Onbutton(self,e):
        var = self.editquote1.GetValue()
        if len(var)==9:
            self.test.SetLabel('True')

        if len(var)==9:
            cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(DPVLDT) as amount
                            FROM [HBGE_Reports].[dbo].[hub_DDJPFile] s
                            where exists (SELECT [ZGDCS]
                            FROM [HUB_DATA].[dbo].[SSCUSTP] d
                            where [ZGIDNO]=?
                            and
                            s.DPACS=d.ZGDCS)""",str(var))
            raw = cursor.fetchone()
            a = raw.amount
            pub.sendMessage("amount", a)


            cursor.execute("""declare @a varchar(20)
                    set @a=?
                    SELECT [DPVLDT]
                          ,[DPCPDT]
                          ,[DPACB]
                          ,[DPACS]
                          ,[DPACX]
                          ,[DPCYCD]     
                          ,[DPDLCD]
                          ,[RCY_AMOUNT]
                          ,[LCY_AMOUNT]
                          ,[DPBLBL]
                          ,[DPNAR1]
                          ,[DPNAR2]
                          ,[DPNAR3]
                          ,[DPNAR4]     
                          FROM [HBGE_Reports].[dbo].[hub_DDJPFile] s
                          where exists (SELECT [ZGDCS]
                          FROM [HUB_DATA].[dbo].[SSCUSTP] d
                          where [ZGIDNO]=@a
                          and
                          s.DPACS=d.ZGDCS)
                          order by [DPVLDT] desc""", str(var))

            rows = cursor.fetchall()

            for i in range(a):
                pub.sendMessage(i, rows[i].DPVLDT)





        else:   
            self.test.SetLabel('False')

    def afterOnbutton(self,e):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Onbutton,e)
        var = self.editquote1.GetValue()
        if len(var)==9:
            self.new = Childframe(None)
            self.new.Show()





class Childframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)




        self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.windowSizer.Add(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 13, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 13)

        pub.subscribe(self.amount, "amount")

        for n in range(3):
            pub.subscribe(self.row, n)


    def amount(self, amount):
        for n in range(amount.data):
            [].append(wx.StaticText(self.panel, id=n, label='test', pos=(20, 30 * n)))
        N = amount.data
        return N

    #I'm having problem here. I can't get N and I don't know how to SetLabel in the static text above 
    def row(self, row):
        for n in range(N):
            [].SetLabel(str(row.data))




if __name__=='__main__':
        app=wx.App(False)
        frame1=Childframe(None)
        frame=Mainframe(None)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is wrong timing between the Childframe creation and the sending of the message. When Mainframe send the message, the new frame does not exist yet and therefore the message is not received by anybody. Try splitting the events bound to the button, instead of:

```
 self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onbutton and self.afterOnbutton)
```

try:

```
self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.afterOnbutton)
```

and modify the code in afterOnbutton such that the other function Onbutton is called after:

```
    def afterOnbutton(self):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Onbutton)
        var = self.editquote1.GetValue()
        if len(var)==9:
            self.new = Childframe(None)
            self.new.Show()

    def Onbutton(self):
        var = self.editquote1.GetValue()
        if len(var)==9:
            self.test.SetLabel('True')
         ... same ...
```

Comment: ok I'll try  but messages are received. problem is that i cant put second message in function which updates creation of function of first massage. thanks for reply

Comment: I am not sure to understand. You can keep sending different messages with the same topic (for example in this case "amount" is a topic) and objects that are subscribed to that topic will keep receiving the new message.

Comment: Yes objects are received and as u see in my example def amount creates static texts with the amount which I send to it. problem is that when static texsts are created i cant change its label.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a handler to the StaticText and then set its value with handler.SetValue("string_value")?